# How is AlexNet MaxPooling implemented before Conv2 layer?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

Can someone please explain how the maxpooling layer is implemented before the conv2 layer in AlexNet? The output of the first conv layer (which is 96 11x11x3 convolution) is 55x55x48 (times 2). Now the paper states that the second conv layer is applied to the output of a maxpooling layer. Assuming the MaxPool is a kernel of 3x3 with stride of 2, this means that the input to the second convolution layer should be (55 - 3)/2 + 1 = 27 but in the picture provided for the AlexNet architecture this is actually the output size of the second conv layer (256 5x5x48 kernel). Am I missing something?

From what I read in the paper this should be the architecture:

```
layer1: Conv
Input: 227x227x3
Kernel: 11x11x3 (stride = 4)
Output: 55x55x48(*2)

layer2: MaxPool
Input: 55x55x48
Kernel: 3x3 (stride = 2)
Output: 27x27x48(*2)

layer3: Conv2
Input: 27x27x48(*2)
Kernel: 5x5x48(*2)
Output: 12x12x128(*2)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the top text and the diagram are not quite one and the same. For starters the input dimensions on the text are 227x227 while in the diagram they are 224x224. Kernel sizes are different as well.

Comment: @photox Actually the input to the architecture is 227x227 instead of 224x224. This is a mistake in the original paper.  Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733636/the-number-of-neurons-in-alexnet)